# Existe alguma forma de comparar todos os valores de itens em um dicionário em python?

Tags: python, dicionário

Existe alguma forma de comparar todos os valores de itens em um dicionário? Por exemplo:

```
a = {'valor1': 4, 'valor2': 5, 'valor3': 4}
b = {'valor1': 2, 'valor2': 2, 'valor3': 8}

if a['valor1']*2<b['valor1']:
    print(f'\033[31m{b[valor1]}\033[m')
else:
    print(f'{b[valor1]}')
```

Eu gostaria de comparar os valores do dicionário a e b e se um valor do dicionário b for 2 vezes maior do que o valor do dicionário a o valor será pintado de vermelho.

PS: Gostaria de comparar o valor1 do a com o valor1 do b, o valor2 do a com o valor2 do b, e assim por diante.

Comment: Os dois dicionários tem exatamente as mesmas chaves?

Comment: sim, as únicas coisas que mudam são os valores

Answer (score 3):

Nix,

Você pode utilizar o método `keys` do dicionário para retornar as chaves do mesmo e com base nisso efetuar as suas comparações:

```
a = {'valor1': 4, 'valor2': 5, 'valor3': 4}
b = {'valor1': 2, 'valor2': 2, 'valor3': 8}

for i in a.keys():
  if a[i] < b[i]:
    print(f'A chave {i} em a é menor')
  else:
    print(f'A chave {i} em b é menor')
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/IdleEcstaticPackagedsoftware

---

Se você precisar validar se a chave existe no dicionário, você pode utilizar o `in`:

```
a = {'valor1': 4, 'valor2': 5, 'valor3': 4}

print('teste' in a)
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/AttractiveSimplisticProspect

Com isso você evitaria acessar uma chave inexistente no dicionário, apenas no caso dos seus dicionários não serem iguais.